Maximizing $\operatorname{Tr}(X)$ subject to $XX^T=I$ and $AX=B$ constraints
I have a $n\times n$ matrix $X$ and I'd like to maximize $\operatorname{Tr}(X)$ subject to $XX^T=I$ and $AX=B$ constraints.
Are there any well-known relaxations/methods to deal with this problem?
This appears to be "quadratically constrained linear problem", and I can find very little about it. I've made it work with a general optimizer
(See StackExchnage Mathematica - Maximizing $\operatorname{Tr}(W)$ subject to orthogonality and linear constraints) but it only works for tiny instances.
Two papers I which give SDP relaxations for related (but not quite the same problems):

The Linear programming on the Stiefel manifold paper which gives SDP relaxation for skinny (rather than square) $X$ and linear inequality constraints.
Ch.13 of Handbook of Semidefinite Programming which gives SDP relaxations for quadratically constrained quadratic problems (rather than linearly constrained quadratic problem)

This problem comes up when dealing with orthogonal weight matrices (See Orthogonal Deep Neural Networks) and making the underconstrained problem well-posed by preferring solutions close with large diagonal.

The problem implies that you have a compatibility condition for $A,B$, right? Otherwise there can not be any solution to the problem.

@WolfgangBangerth yes I'm looking at under constrained case

One approach could be, to phrase this as an optimisation problem over the Rotataions manifold (https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/rotations.html); you would need the Riemannian gradient of (minus) the trace as well as the (component wise) Riemannian gradient of the remaining equality constraint, then with a feasible start point you could run https://manoptjl.org/stable/solvers/interior_point_Newton/ . I got a bit stuck on the Riemannian gradients for the constraints sadly.

Sketch of a full solution:

Up to a change of basis (use a $RQ$ factorization of $A$ and left-multiply by $R^{-1}$) you may assume $A = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which means that you are looking for orthogonal matrices $X = \begin{bmatrix}X_1\\ X_2\end{bmatrix}$ with a prescribed first block of rows $X_1=B$.

Complete $B$ to an orthogonal matrix $\begin{bmatrix}B\\ C\end{bmatrix}$, with $C = \begin{bmatrix}C_{1} & C_{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $C_2$ square. Then the only constraint on $X_2$ is $X_2^T X_2 = I - X_1^T X_1 = I - B^T B = C^T C$. This means that $X_2 = QC$, for some orthogonal matrix $C$. We have reduced the problem to
$$
    \max_{\text{$Q$ orthogonal}} Tr(QC_2).
$$

This last problem has a closed-form solution; see for instance this MSE question: $Q^*$ is the orthogonal factor in the polar decomposition of $C_2$.



I'm curious whether any of the other answers or comments could be modified to apply to this version of the problem. From a computational standpoint, this seems like a very advantageous preprocessing step to reduce the dimension

True. In the end the final problem is: given a matrix $C$, find an orthogonal $Q$ that maximizes $\operatorname{Tr}(QC)$.

It seems like such a problem should have a closed form as you suggest. Some manifold analysis like other suggest would likely make short work of this

@whpowell96 Here is the missing piece of the puzzle! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754301/find-the-maximum-of-operatornametrrz-over-all-orthogonal-matrices-r

Nice concise explanation. BTW, another write-up with functioning code is here

Another more intuitive way to see this final result is to notice that we are maximizing an inner product over a convex set so it is extremized by the closest orthogonal matrix to $Q$

I believe you can formulate this as an optimization over Riemannian manifolds with linear equality constraints. As $X$ is orthogonal, we seek:
\begin{align}
&\min_{X\in \mathbb{O}(n)} -\mathrm{Tr}(X) \\
& \mathrm{s.t.}\quad AX=B.
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{O}(n)$ is the manifold of orthogonal matrices. Note that Stiefel manifold is just a generalization of this to $k$-frames. A naive approach would convert the problem into an unconstrained Riemannian optimization and try to minimize:
\begin{align}
&\min_{X\in \mathbb{O}(n)} -\mathrm{Tr}(X) + \lambda\|AX-B\|^2_2,
\end{align}
for some $\lambda>0$. Any standard package such as $\mathrm{manopt}$ would be able to solve this with ease, for example via trust-regions. If the problem is feasible and behaves 'nicely', for large enough $\lambda$, the solution should get pretty close to satisfying all constraints.
Another approach involves respecting the hard linear equality constraints at our disposal and attempting the first problem directly. For that, we can turn to the methods for Riemannian optimization with constraints. Riemannian augmented Lagrangian or Riemannian Exact Penalty Methods can be useful here. They are covered in:

Liu, Changshuo, and Nicolas Boumal. Simple algorithms for optimization on Riemannian manifolds with constraints. Applied Mathematics & Optimization 82.3 (2020).

The source code is also openly available.

this can be formulated in JuMP.jl fairly simply.
using JuMP, Ipopt LinearAlgebra
n = 100
A = rand(40, n)
B = rand(40, n)
model = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
@variable(model, X[1:n, 1:n])
for i = 1:n
    for j = i:n
        @constraint(model, dot(X[:, i],X[:, j]) == (i==j))
    end
end
@constraint(model, A*X==B)
@objective(model, Max, tr(X))
optimize!(model)

For n=20, this took 12 iterations and solved in 0.1 seconds. For n=100 it is notably slower, but still seems to be making progress

Interesting! What kind of method does this use?

as written this is just nonlinear optimization with a nice interface. the great thing about jump though is that it is a solver agnostic way to write models, so if you discover a solver that supports these orthogonality constraints, you can sub it in with a single line of code change

Ipopt.Optimizer is a Julia wrapper for this open source interior point optimizer from COIN-OR. There are some cited publications on the linked page. The Julia package contains other algorithms implemented in Julia or wrapped from elsewhere

This isn't an answer, but an observation: The fact that you need $XX^T=I$ and that $X$ is a square matrix means that you're looking for orthogonal matrices. The eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices all have modulus 1, and in particular if they are symmetric, the eigenvalues are either minus one or plus one. In that case, the trace of these matrices is discrete: It's the number of positive eigenvalues minus the number of negative eigenvalues. As a consequence, this is not a differentiable problem.
What that implies is that the problem is only really interesting if you are not only considering symmetric matrices because in that case the eigenvalues can be complex (but must appear in conjugate pairs) and in that case the trace is the sum of the real parts of the eigenvalues, which form a continuum.

Yeah, I think symmetric constraint is quite strong, using the strictly real version of Spectral Theorem (Handbook of Linear Algebra, 8-6), aka real Schur form, we can see that in the Schur basis the set of symmetric orthogonal matrices has measure 0
